# Maintain count of paragraphs , Lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

My aim is to acquire the count of a paragraph whilst iterating over w:p tags .
I used:

```
 for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p', namespaces={'w':w}):
        paracount+=1
```

In the above expression , I want to increase paracount with paragraphs i.e 1st paragraph will have `paracount`=1 and 2nd will have `paracount` = 2 and so on.. but this actually increases paracount with every element(tags) in a paragraph.. how could I go around this one?

something like:

```
for w in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:', namespaces={'w':w}):
    #increase paracount if p tag encountered (need help here)
    #iterate over p
    #perform remaining operations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of increasing it yourself:

```
for paracount, p in enumerate(lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p', namespaces={'w':w}), 1):
    # Do something with `paracount` and `p`.
```